# How to open a mounted file server in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, fileserver

**NOTE: Trying to access file server not ftp server.**

I have tried 'open_uri', 'File.open', HTTParty'. Is there any other way to connect to the file server from rails app.

Tried Methods:

```
open('\\\\PAZ02DSD9\\sample_path\\file.abc');
               or
File.open('\\\\PAZ02DSD9\\sample_path\\file.abc');
               or
HTTParty.get('\\\\PAZ02DSD9\\sample_path\\file.abc');
```

The HTTParty will get http protocols so it wont work.

Usually In **C#.net** the following code is used will fetch data from file server.

```
File.OpenRead('\\\\PAZ02DSD9\\sample_path\\file.abc');
```

But When I try to access same thing using **open_uri** or **File** I am getting:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - \\PAZ02DSD920\sample_path\file.abc
from (irb):1:in `initialize'
from (irb):1:in `open'
from (irb):1
from /Users/brilliomac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

But File is available in that location.
How to get this file in rails application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]". You need to give us a lot more information for us to help you. Where's your minimal code demonstrating the problem? Why didn't it work? Did you get errors?

Comment: @theTinMan I have updated the question with what I tried Hope it will make clear.